# My HTTP response from custom web server doesn't get recognized as a HTTP message

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, http, tcp

I was learning about sockets and socket programming from a book and I wanted to experiment by creating a simple web server. Here's the code:

```
import socket

welcomingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
welcomingSocket.bind(('', 80))

welcomingSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = welcomingSocket.accept()

    request = connectionSocket.recv(1024)

    #Doesn't get recognised as an http message by wireshark
    response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT\r\n\
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)\r\n\
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT\r\n\
Content-Length: 88\r\n\
Content-Type: text/html\r\n\
Connection: Closed\r\n\
\r\n\
<html>\r\n\
<body>\r\n\
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>\r\n\
</body>\r\n\
</html>\r\n\
\r\n"

    connectionSocket.send(response.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Everything works okay except that when I access my IP through a browser, I can't see the website. Moreover, I used Wireshark to see what's going on and saw that my response is not recognized by Wireshark as an HTTP message, only as a TCP segment.

I really want to know why it doesn't work. Is it because the dates I send are not correct or maybe the formatting of the message is off?

Btw. I copied this HTTP response message from a webpage.

Comment: *"Btw. I copied this HTTP response message from a webpage."* - whatever the source was, it is wrong (or your copied it wrong) in addition to the Content-length mentioned in the answer. There is no `Connection: Closed` but only `Connection: close` (i.e. close not closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it to work with this (port changed such that it runs as a regular user under Linux :) )

```
import socket

welcomingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
welcomingSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8196))

welcomingSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = welcomingSocket.accept()

    request = connectionSocket.recv(1024)

    response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT\r\n\
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)\r\n\
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT\r\n\
Content-Length: 60\r\n\
Content-Type: text/html\r\n\
Connection: Closed\r\n\
\r\n\
<html>\r\n\
<body>\r\n\
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>\r\n\
</body>\r\n\
</html>\r\n\
\r\n"

    connectionSocket.send(response.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Basically, the error was in the line

> `Content-Length: 88`

That needs to be 60.

It is the wrong length causing Chromium to refuse the page (it tells you about it in it's web developer tools including a specific and helpful error message). Interestingly, Firefox displays the original variant (with the wrong content length) without issues here.

Having changed the content length, Wireshark also accepts it as HTTP :)